# How to click to expand and resize other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

On my web page, I am trying to make it so that when the user presses "Link 1" it triggers an animated expansion of div `#section1`. If there were any previously open divs, they would hide, close first before expanding `#section1`.

While the expanded `#section1` is in the open state, clicking "Link 1" can hide #section1.

The same consistent behavior applies for "Link 2" with `#section2`, and "Link3" with `#section3`

See [animated gif of desired behavior](http://www.mediafire.com/view/pjbzg2egg4e8zsm/Untitled-1.gif).

Can anyone help me please?

HTML:

```html
<div id="navbar">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#section1">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div id="section1"></div>
   <div id="section2"></div>
   <div id="section3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are 3 tasks you need to be done:

1. Changing content sections
2. Clickable nav items
3. Animation effects

Let's start changing content sections. I advise you to add them class like .section. The simplest way is using display property:

```
.section {display: none}
.section.active {display: block}
```

Then you need some JS for make nav items clickable:

```
$("#navbar").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    // cross browser href parsing
    var $tab = $("#" + e.currentTarget.href.split("#")[1]);
    // toggle one tab's visibility and close others if need
    $tab.toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    // prevent default
    return !1
})
```

The last part is animation effects. You need to use css transitions:

```
.section {transition: all 0.5s}
```

Here is a very simple example – http://codepen.io/korzhik/pen/epwaEJ

By the way, you can use CSS transform property to animate with a "slide" effect. It has a better performance.

Comment: Thanks Man It's This what I looking for you helped me very much Thanks again Man

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#navbar a').bind('click', function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.container div').removeClass('active');
        $('.container '+ href).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: (And if "Link 1" is pressed again, then #section1 will be hidden.) that is what OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

1st: don't forget to include Jquery

2nd: just use this code

```
<script>
    $('#navbar > ul > li > a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.container div[id^="section"]:not('+href+')').slideUp();
        $('.container '+ href).slideToggle();
    });
</script>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9hmdr117/)

Comment: Thank you it's work finally Thanks for your help , how can i make it start from the left ?

Comment: @RamyMohamed You're Welcome .. I know you need to show it from left to right  but  if you post your css or update my working demo with your css  I will modify it to fit your need :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#navbar a');

links.forEach(function(link){
     var sectionId = link.href;
     var section = document.querySelector(sectionId)
     section.addEventListner('click', function(){
         var isOpen = this.classList.contains('slide-in');

         this.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
     }) 
})
```

```
 .container > div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.slide-in {
    animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.5s forwards;
}

.slide-out {
    animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: slide-out 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
    100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
    0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-out {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```